# Intercept and forward DynamoDB traffic using aws-sdk-go

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

I have an use case where I have services which require interaction with DynamoDB (Programming env is in `golang`). But assume these service doesn't have AWS credentials and I have custom AuthN/AuthZ mechanism to validate the services internally and set credentials. So, I want to write a AuthN proxy service which intercepts requests to DynamoDB, check what type of operation (Get/Set/Delete), validate them, set DDB credentials to that request, query dynamodb and send response back to clients. I tried using proxy as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html#configuring-a-proxy) in DDB documentation, but it is HTTP Connect tunnelling and I couldn't intercept traffic in between as it is HTTPS traffic to DynamoDB. Can someone tell me how I can achieve this using AWS Go sdk library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have time now to figure it out in detail, but it looks to me like the way to go is to leverage the SDK client [Handlers](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/f401f4e72ca19632543be38c564a063827084a01/aws/handlers.go#L10). See [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/f401f4e72ca19632543be38c564a063827084a01/aws/client.go#L78-L85) how they inject some debugging, for example. As another example, NewRelic made use of this feature [here](https://github.com/newrelic/go-agent/blob/50605a92eae9be54f810c677fc1ac0a38c5fc70b/_integrations/nrawssdk/v2/nrawssdk.go#L28-L85).